# Javascript regex for email excluding '[' and ']'

Tags: javascript, regex

I  am trying to make regex for email my regex is:

```
^(?:[0-9a-zA-z.!!@#$%^&*+={}'/-]+@[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z]+[/.][a-zA-Z]{2,4}|)$
```

According to this regex it should accept special characters as mentioned in rule but sholud not accept `[` and `]` but it accepting `[` and `]`

I want to use this regex but it should exclude `[` and `]`

How can I do that?

Comment: `[/.]` you are looking for slash or dot there (before tld)? Did you mean `[\.]` which is the same as `[.]` which is the same as `\.`? Also tlds may be more than 4 chars. And what's with the last `|`?

Comment: Maybe just ``^(?:([0-9a-zA-z.]+)@[a-zA-Z]{2,}[/.][a-zA-Z]{2,4}|)$``

Comment: You should have a look at: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: If your validating input from html on client-side better use `<input type="email" ...` (html5) (plus, maybe, required attr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want validate email, then regular expression will be look like this:

```
^(?:[0-9a-zA-z.]+@[a-zA-Z]{2,}[/.][a-zA-Z]{2,4}|)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ktRrL4mFg_huLTaX)

But it very simplified. Full version here http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

**UPD:**
Just typo in original regular expression `A-z` -> `A-Z`

```
^(?:[0-9a-zA-Z\.!@#$%^&*+={}'/-]+@[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z]+[/.][a-zA-Z]{2,4}|)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/oeP-4NPniWxDyreL)

Comment: Thanks Alesksey But as per requirement email can accept special characters like .!!@#$%^&*+={}'/- but it should not accept "[" and "]" my regex is working fine but it is also accepting "[" and "]" which is not accepted

Comment: Here is typo in your regular expression ``A-z`` when need ``A-Z``, if you fix it then regexp will work right. See update of answer